# A set cookie is not found with php

Tags: php, cookies

I have successfully set a cookie `cad` and can see it in firefox cookie-search.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cad'])){
echo'YES';
}else{
echo'NO';
}

//parse NO
```

I am setting up my website on a hosted server, about to change from another so the server is site.com.test.host.com. Does that create problem for calling the cookie?

But talking against that is that `print_r($_COOKIE);` shows other Cookies on the same test-domain.

Comment: What is the path (the bit of the URL after the domain name) of the file where the cookie is set? What is the path of the file where you're looking for the cookie?

Comment: Cookies are only accessible on the domain where the cookie is created.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks that was it! `setcookie("cad", encrypt($abc, $xyz), time()+3600*24*30,"/"); worked

Comment: @Joseph I'll post it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a cookie, you can set various options.  Cookies, as everyone knows, can only be accessed by scripts on the same domain, but you can also affect what *path* the cookie is set on.  For instance, a cookie set on `/foo/bar.php` may not be accessible on `/foobar.php`.

PHP by default sets the cookie to the current path.  So, with the above example, the cookie is set to the path `/foo/`, and is not accessible outside that path.

When you set your cookies, therefore, it's best to be explicit about where you want them to be available.  In PHP this is very easy; just set an extra parameter specifying the path.  As you indicate in the comments, you need the most liberal path possible `/`, which means "anywhere on this domain".

```
setcookie('cad', 'somevalue', 0, '/');
```

See [the `setcookie` documentation  in the PHP manual](http://php.net/setcookie).