# php cookie sets but when getting it back it is not found

Tags: php, cookies, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A set cookie is not found with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617413/a-set-cookie-is-not-found-with-php)

I have set a cookie with php and I can see it is set with my browser. when i try to get it back (from other page on the same website) it seems that doesn't found.
here is how I set the cookie:

```
 setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365);
```

and I'm getting it back like this:

```
$_COOKIE['login'];
```

thanks

Comment: are you setting the cookie and checking for it on the same script, or is the check on another page?

Comment: how are you using it on other pages?  more code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting a cookie then checking if it exists on the same page. Because I've tried that and it can only be accessed on a new page load. You can try having a page that sets the cookie then have a page that checks if the cookie exists.

Here is what PHP Manual says:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

You may want to `echo $_COOKIE['logon'];`
or add `setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365, "/");`

Comment: thanks, it has to be set like this: setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365, "\"); or like this: setcookie("login",$login, "\" time()+86400*365); ??

Comment: setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365, "\"); just like what the manual says http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: it actually has to be:setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365, "\\");

Comment: but it Still doesn't work! what to try?

Comment: `setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365, "\\");` "\\" = path to your scripts location. The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.  You might even need to add the domain part `setcookie("login",$login, time()+86400*365, $path, $domain);`

Comment: the cookie path should be `/`. backslashes for path separators is a windowsism

Comment: Woops sorry I just copied Vald's response, my original answer says '/' and thanks @MarcB. I sometimes get confused with /'s and \'s